# losing internet connection after enable repository in RHEL 7 (on VMware workstation 14)

Tags: wget, yum, rhel7, vmware-workstation

I install RHEL 7 on VMware workstation 14 using the .iso file. then I tried using yum command, but I faced with this error: 
**This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
There are no enabled repos.
Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.**
So I mount .iso file and using it as a repository (i found this solution in this website https://linuxconfig.org/rhel-7-solution-to-there-are-no-enabled-repos-message) then yum command works fine. But now I lost my internet connection which I had before enabling repository, so I think there is the relation between these two. 
any idea how can I have internet connection in my RHEL7? (i really need it for wget, curl command, etc.)
Thanks in advance.